# r alphahull post-processing/ avoid two hulls

Tags: r

I have got a table with coordinates of points and want to get the smalest polygon around them. I tried different functions and so far alphahull works best for my purposes. My major interest is in the area of the hull. I have got approximately 3500 datasets, so I have to find a reliable method for my analysis.

I analysed some datasets and realised that in some cases I get a hull in a hull and `areahull()` is not able to return an area. A higher alpha-value would avoid this but would overestimate my area by far.

Is there a possibility to post-process my alpha-hull to remove the second hull? Or a better method to get the size of the area?

```
library(alphahull)
tmp <- ahull(path.points.1$x, path.points.1$y, alpha = 50)
plot(tmp, wpoints = F)
```

[image: Plot: Alpha = 50]

[lin to example dataset](https://bokubox.boku.ac.at/index.php/#15de281dc9fc5e161ef322c839095c75)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which seems to work for my purposes: the function `ahull_track()` returns only the boundary as a `geom_path()`-object. the coordinates of the single boundary segments are stored in a list. unfortunately they are not in the correct order, so it is no straight-forward solution. I had to write a function which rearranges the segments into the correct order and generates a polygon.