# ahull_track issue: 'could not find function "psp"'

Tags: r, function, r-package, concave-hull

I've been working with the R library `alphahull` for a few days now.
As I'm trying to get the results as `sf` polygons, I'm following the recommandation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472247/r-alphahull-post-processing-avoid-two-hulls) to use `ahull_track`, as that returns `geom_path` objects.

However, when I try it, I run into this issue:

```r
Error in psp(dat[-np, 1], dat[-np, 2], dat[-1, 1], dat[-1, 2], window = owin(range(dat[,  : 
  could not find function "psp"
```

I did look at the code of function itself on [Github](https://github.com/cran/alphahull/blob/master/R/ahull_track.R), and indeed I see it calls `psp` on line 8, but without any reference as to which library it shouls be loaded from.

Anyone knows what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

After trying out one by one the different libraries mentioned in the documentation's **Import** (see below), I found out what I was missing.

[image]

It turned out to be `spatstat`.

Strange that calling `require(alphahull)` doesn't automatically call `require(spatstat)`.

Comment: It's a bug. A package should automatically load its dependencies.